# The use of the word you as opposed to your in the same sentance

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between: “I object to you making payments” and “I object to your making payments”?

Answer (score 1):

Although in casual conversation people often use both **you** and **your** indiscriminately, there is a difference between them.

> > I object to you making payments

means that your objection is to the person who is making the payments. That's to say that the *objector* might be perfectly happy to see the payments being made but not by the individual concerned.

> > I object to your making payments

means that your objection is to what the person is doing - the action itself - not to the person as an individual.

In most circumstances, this distinction is blurred as it often comes down to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> *I object to [you making payments].*
>
> *I object to [your making payments].*

There's no difference in meaning or syntax. In both cases, the pronoun is subject of the gerund-participial clause.

The fact that the subject can be genitive "your" or non-genitive "you" makes no difference. There is nothing noun-like about the genitive construction, and its analysis as a clause with "your" as subject is unproblematic.

The only difference is stylistic with the genitive generally considered the more formal alternant.